# correct `go vet` warning about wrong format argument

Tags: go

I have a struct that contains a pointer to another struct.  That is,

```
type InnerStruct struct {
    whatever bool
}

type OuterStruct struct {
    is *InnerStruct
}
```

If I print out an instance of `OuterStruct` with `%+v`, then the inner struct is not expanded like it would be if it weren't a pointer.  I understand and accept why that is, but because I don't have any chance of recursion, I'd like to get the full thing printed out.

It occurred to me that I might be able to implement the `Formatter` interface on a pointer receiver of `InnerStruct` in order to get the behavior I want, and indeed, the following does exactly what I want, at least for the cases I had (perhaps there are ways in which it could go horribly wrong; please tell me!):

```
func (is *InnerStruct) Format(s fmt.State, verb rune) {
    switch verb {
    case 'v':
        if s.Flag('+') {
            fmt.Fprintf(s, "&%+v", *is)
        } else if s.Flag('#') {
            fmt.Fprintf(s, "&%#v", *is)
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(s, "&%v", *is)
        }
    case 's':
        fmt.Fprintf(s, "&%s", *is)
    }
}
```

But when I run `go vet` on the code, it complains:

```
./thing.go:341: Fprintf format %s has arg *s of wrong type thing.InnerStruct
```

Is there a better way to get at the default string representation of a struct that avoids this issue with `vet`?

FWIW, I tried [`go-spew`](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew), and got (almost) the exact output I wanted, so I'll probably just go down that route, but I'd still like to know what, if anything, could be done to satisfy `vet`.

Answer (score 3):

You have duplicate names `s *InnerStruct` and `s fmt.State`. `go vet` complains, that you have format verb `s` instead of `v`: `fmt.Fprintf(s, "&%s", *s)`.

Fix your typos. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type InnerStruct struct {
    whatever bool
}

type OuterStruct struct {
    is *InnerStruct
}

func (s *InnerStruct) Format(f fmt.State, verb rune) {
    switch verb {
    case 'v':
        if f.Flag('+') {
            fmt.Fprintf(f, "&%+v", *s)
        } else if f.Flag('#') {
            fmt.Fprintf(f, "&%#v", *s)
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(f, "&%v", *s)
        }
    case 's':
        fmt.Fprintf(f, "&%v", *s)
    }
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/B2pAus3kEwt

Comment: My apologies; in simplifying my test case, I neglected to rebuild the result. However, after fixing those issues, the "problem" with `go vet` remains.